# How do I bring the subview over the scroll view on iOS?

Tags: ios

In iOS development, I want to add a subview in a viewbased application. I am having scrollview above that am having views containing labels and I used Interface Builder to design these views.

How do I bring the subview over the scroll view?

Answer (score 0):

The way I do do this in IB is set the View Mode in the document window to Outline View (2nd button). Then I drag the view from the library on top of the scroll view and it will be inserted as a subview of the scrollview.

If you get a disclosure triangle next to your scrollview it will have had the new view inserted as a subview.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean in the xib, drag the scroll view in first then drag your other subviews onto the scroll view.

If you mean programmatically, this should work:

```
[scrollView addSubview: mySubview];
```